# Spring boot metrics

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, metrics

I´m very new at this, actually, I´m studying to become a developer but I have a problem. My teacher is a terrible one and google doesn´t really help me. My problem is that I just created a project with Jhipster and I need to make some queries in order to test them in postman but I don´t even know where to start. Can somebody guide me through this? I would really appreciate it, the 3 metrics I need to create are:

- For a specific player, whose nickname must be provided with a list of games won.
- For a given player, a number of games won.
- List of players who have a playing a given game.

**Here are the relations:**

```
entity Player {
    nickname String unique pattern(/[a-zA-Z0-9_]+/),
    name String,
    surname String,
    dateOfBirth LocalDate
}

entity Game {
  winnerPoints Integer,
    gamePlayed String    
}

relationship ManyToOne {
  Game{winner(nickname) required} to Player,
  Game{looser(nickname) required} to Player 
}

dto all with mapstruct
service all with serviceClass
paginate Player, Game with infinite-scroll
```

**PlayerResource.java:**

```
/**
 * REST controller for managing {@link com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Player}.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PlayerResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PlayerResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "player";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final PlayerService playerService;

    private final PlayerRepository playerRepository;

    public PlayerResource(PlayerService playerService, PlayerRepository playerRepository) {
        this.playerService = playerService;
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /players} : Create a new player.
     *
     * @param playerDTO the playerDTO to create.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 201 (Created)} and with body the new playerDTO, or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the player has already an ID.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PostMapping("/players")
    public ResponseEntity<PlayerDTO> createPlayer(@Valid @RequestBody PlayerDTO playerDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Player : {}", playerDTO);
        if (playerDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new player cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        PlayerDTO result = playerService.save(playerDTO);
        return ResponseEntity
            .created(new URI("/api/players/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * {@code PUT  /players/:id} : Updates an existing player.
     *
     * @param id the id of the playerDTO to save.
     * @param playerDTO the playerDTO to update.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body the updated playerDTO,
     * or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the playerDTO is not valid,
     * or with status {@code 500 (Internal Server Error)} if the playerDTO couldn't be updated.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PutMapping("/players/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PlayerDTO> updatePlayer(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) final Long id,
        @Valid @RequestBody PlayerDTO playerDTO
    ) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Player : {}, {}", id, playerDTO);
        if (playerDTO.getId() == null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(id, playerDTO.getId())) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idinvalid");
        }

        if (!playerRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Entity not found", ENTITY_NAME, "idnotfound");
        }

        PlayerDTO result = playerService.update(playerDTO);
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, playerDTO.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * {@code PATCH  /players/:id} : Partial updates given fields of an existing player, field will ignore if it is null
     *
     * @param id the id of the playerDTO to save.
     * @param playerDTO the playerDTO to update.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body the updated playerDTO,
     * or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the playerDTO is not valid,
     * or with status {@code 404 (Not Found)} if the playerDTO is not found,
     * or with status {@code 500 (Internal Server Error)} if the playerDTO couldn't be updated.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PatchMapping(value = "/players/{id}", consumes = { "application/json", "application/merge-patch+json" })
    public ResponseEntity<PlayerDTO> partialUpdatePlayer(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) final Long id,
        @NotNull @RequestBody PlayerDTO playerDTO
    ) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to partial update Player partially : {}, {}", id, playerDTO);
        if (playerDTO.getId() == null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(id, playerDTO.getId())) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idinvalid");
        }

        if (!playerRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Entity not found", ENTITY_NAME, "idnotfound");
        }

        Optional<PlayerDTO> result = playerService.partialUpdate(playerDTO);

        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(
            result,
            HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, playerDTO.getId().toString())
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@code GET  /players} : get all the players.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and the list of players in body.
     */
    @GetMapping("/players")
    public ResponseEntity<List<PlayerDTO>> getAllPlayers(@org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Players");
        Page<PlayerDTO> page = playerService.findAll(pageable);
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }

    /**
     * {@code GET  /players/:id} : get the "id" player.
     *
     * @param id the id of the playerDTO to retrieve.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body the playerDTO, or with status {@code 404 (Not Found)}.
     */
    @GetMapping("/players/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<PlayerDTO> getPlayer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Player : {}", id);
        Optional<PlayerDTO> playerDTO = playerService.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(playerDTO);
    }

    /**
     * {@code DELETE  /players/:id} : delete the "id" player.
     *
     * @param id the id of the playerDTO to delete.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 204 (NO_CONTENT)}.
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/players/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deletePlayer(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Player : {}", id);
        playerService.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity
            .noContent()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, id.toString()))
            .build();
    }
}
```

**GameResource.java:**

```
/**
 * REST controller for managing {@link com.mycompany.myapp.domain.Game}.
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class GameResource {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GameResource.class);

    private static final String ENTITY_NAME = "game";

    @Value("${jhipster.clientApp.name}")
    private String applicationName;

    private final GameService gameService;

    private final GameRepository gameRepository;

    public GameResource(GameService gameService, GameRepository gameRepository) {
        this.gameService = gameService;
        this.gameRepository = gameRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@code POST  /games} : Create a new game.
     *
     * @param gameDTO the gameDTO to create.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 201 (Created)} and with body the new gameDTO, or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the game has already an ID.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PostMapping("/games")
    public ResponseEntity<GameDTO> createGame(@Valid @RequestBody GameDTO gameDTO) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save Game : {}", gameDTO);
        if (gameDTO.getId() != null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("A new game cannot already have an ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idexists");
        }
        GameDTO result = gameService.save(gameDTO);
        return ResponseEntity
            .created(new URI("/api/games/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * {@code PUT  /games/:id} : Updates an existing game.
     *
     * @param id the id of the gameDTO to save.
     * @param gameDTO the gameDTO to update.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body the updated gameDTO,
     * or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the gameDTO is not valid,
     * or with status {@code 500 (Internal Server Error)} if the gameDTO couldn't be updated.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PutMapping("/games/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<GameDTO> updateGame(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) final Long id,
        @Valid @RequestBody GameDTO gameDTO
    ) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to update Game : {}, {}", id, gameDTO);
        if (gameDTO.getId() == null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(id, gameDTO.getId())) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idinvalid");
        }

        if (!gameRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Entity not found", ENTITY_NAME, "idnotfound");
        }

        GameDTO result = gameService.update(gameDTO);
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, gameDTO.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }

    /**
     * {@code PATCH  /games/:id} : Partial updates given fields of an existing game, field will ignore if it is null
     *
     * @param id the id of the gameDTO to save.
     * @param gameDTO the gameDTO to update.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body the updated gameDTO,
     * or with status {@code 400 (Bad Request)} if the gameDTO is not valid,
     * or with status {@code 404 (Not Found)} if the gameDTO is not found,
     * or with status {@code 500 (Internal Server Error)} if the gameDTO couldn't be updated.
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect.
     */
    @PatchMapping(value = "/games/{id}", consumes = { "application/json", "application/merge-patch+json" })
    public ResponseEntity<GameDTO> partialUpdateGame(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = false) final Long id,
        @NotNull @RequestBody GameDTO gameDTO
    ) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to partial update Game partially : {}, {}", id, gameDTO);
        if (gameDTO.getId() == null) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid id", ENTITY_NAME, "idnull");
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(id, gameDTO.getId())) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Invalid ID", ENTITY_NAME, "idinvalid");
        }

        if (!gameRepository.existsById(id)) {
            throw new BadRequestAlertException("Entity not found", ENTITY_NAME, "idnotfound");
        }

        Optional<GameDTO> result = gameService.partialUpdate(gameDTO);

        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(
            result,
            HeaderUtil.createEntityUpdateAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, gameDTO.getId().toString())
        );
    }

    /**
     * {@code GET  /games} : get all the games.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information.
     * @param eagerload flag to eager load entities from relationships (This is applicable for many-to-many).
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and the list of games in body.
     */
    @GetMapping("/games")
    public ResponseEntity<List<GameDTO>> getAllGames(
        @org.springdoc.api.annotations.ParameterObject Pageable pageable,
        @RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "true") boolean eagerload
    ) {
        log.debug("REST request to get a page of Games");
        Page<GameDTO> page;
        if (eagerload) {
            page = gameService.findAllWithEagerRelationships(pageable);
        } else {
            page = gameService.findAll(pageable);
        }
        HttpHeaders headers = PaginationUtil.generatePaginationHttpHeaders(ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest(), page);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers).body(page.getContent());
    }

    /**
     * {@code GET  /games/:id} : get the "id" game.
     *
     * @param id the id of the gameDTO to retrieve.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 200 (OK)} and with body the gameDTO, or with status {@code 404 (Not Found)}.
     */
    @GetMapping("/games/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<GameDTO> getGame(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to get Game : {}", id);
        Optional<GameDTO> gameDTO = gameService.findOne(id);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(gameDTO);
    }

    /**
     * {@code DELETE  /games/:id} : delete the "id" game.
     *
     * @param id the id of the gameDTO to delete.
     * @return the {@link ResponseEntity} with status {@code 204 (NO_CONTENT)}.
     */
    @DeleteMapping("/games/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> deleteGame(@PathVariable Long id) {
        log.debug("REST request to delete Game : {}", id);
        gameService.delete(id);
        return ResponseEntity
            .noContent()
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityDeletionAlert(applicationName, false, ENTITY_NAME, id.toString()))
            .build();
    }
}
```

**PlayerRepository.Java:**

```
/**
 * Spring Data SQL repository for the Player entity.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface PlayerRepository extends JpaRepository<Player, Long> {}
```

**GameRepository.java:**

```
/**
 * Spring Data SQL repository for the Game entity.
 */
@Repository
public interface GameRepository extends JpaRepository<Game, Long> {
    default Optional<Game> findOneWithEagerRelationships(Long id) {
        return this.findOneWithToOneRelationships(id);
    }

    default List<Game> findAllWithEagerRelationships() {
        return this.findAllWithToOneRelationships();
    }

    default Page<Game> findAllWithEagerRelationships(Pageable pageable) {
        return this.findAllWithToOneRelationships(pageable);
    }

    @Query(
        value = "select distinct game from Game game left join fetch game.winner left join fetch game.looser",
        countQuery = "select count(distinct game) from Game game"
    )
    Page<Game> findAllWithToOneRelationships(Pageable pageable);

    @Query("select distinct game from Game game left join fetch game.winner left join fetch game.looser")
    List<Game> findAllWithToOneRelationships();

    @Query("select game from Game game left join fetch game.winner left join fetch game.looser where game.id =:id")
    Optional<Game> findOneWithToOneRelationships(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

**PlayerService.java**

```
/**
 * Service Implementation for managing {@link Player}.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class PlayerService {
    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PlayerService.class);
    private final PlayerRepository playerRepository;
    private final PlayerMapper playerMapper;
    public PlayerService(PlayerRepository playerRepository, PlayerMapper playerMapper) {
        this.playerRepository = playerRepository;
        this.playerMapper = playerMapper;
    }
    /**
     * Save a player.
     *
     * @param playerDTO the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public PlayerDTO save(PlayerDTO playerDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Player : {}", playerDTO);
        Player player = playerMapper.toEntity(playerDTO);
        player = playerRepository.save(player);
        return playerMapper.toDto(player);
    }
    /**
     * Update a player.
     *
     * @param playerDTO the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public PlayerDTO update(PlayerDTO playerDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Player : {}", playerDTO);
        Player player = playerMapper.toEntity(playerDTO);
        player = playerRepository.save(player);
        return playerMapper.toDto(player);
    }
    /**
     * Partially update a player.
     *
     * @param playerDTO the entity to update partially.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public Optional<PlayerDTO> partialUpdate(PlayerDTO playerDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to partially update Player : {}", playerDTO);
        return playerRepository
            .findById(playerDTO.getId())
            .map(existingPlayer -> {
                playerMapper.partialUpdate(existingPlayer, playerDTO);
                return existingPlayer;
            })
            .map(playerRepository::save)
            .map(playerMapper::toDto);
    }
    /**
     * Get all the players.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information.
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<PlayerDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Players");
        return playerRepository.findAll(pageable).map(playerMapper::toDto);
    }
    /**
     * Get one player by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return the entity.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<PlayerDTO> findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Player : {}", id);
        return playerRepository.findById(id).map(playerMapper::toDto);
    }
    /**
     * Delete the player by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     */
    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Player : {}", id);
        playerRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

**GameService.java**:

```
    /**

 * Service Implementation for managing {@link Game}.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class GameService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GameService.class);

    private final GameRepository gameRepository;

    private final GameMapper gameMapper;

    public GameService(GameRepository gameRepository, GameMapper gameMapper) {
        this.gameRepository = gameRepository;
        this.gameMapper = gameMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Save a game.
     *
     * @param gameDTO the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public GameDTO save(GameDTO gameDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Game : {}", gameDTO);
        Game game = gameMapper.toEntity(gameDTO);
        game = gameRepository.save(game);
        return gameMapper.toDto(game);
    }

    /**
     * Update a game.
     *
     * @param gameDTO the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public GameDTO update(GameDTO gameDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Game : {}", gameDTO);
        Game game = gameMapper.toEntity(gameDTO);
        game = gameRepository.save(game);
        return gameMapper.toDto(game);
    }

    /**
     * Partially update a game.
     *
     * @param gameDTO the entity to update partially.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    public Optional<GameDTO> partialUpdate(GameDTO gameDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to partially update Game : {}", gameDTO);

        return gameRepository
            .findById(gameDTO.getId())
            .map(existingGame -> {
                gameMapper.partialUpdate(existingGame, gameDTO);

                return existingGame;
            })
            .map(gameRepository::save)
            .map(gameMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Get all the games.
     *
     * @param pageable the pagination information.
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Page<GameDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable) {
        log.debug("Request to get all Games");
        return gameRepository.findAll(pageable).map(gameMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Get all the games with eager load of many-to-many relationships.
     *
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    public Page<GameDTO> findAllWithEagerRelationships(Pageable pageable) {
        return gameRepository.findAllWithEagerRelationships(pageable).map(gameMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Get one game by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return the entity.
     */
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<GameDTO> findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Game : {}", id);
        return gameRepository.findOneWithEagerRelationships(id).map(gameMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the game by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     */
    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Game : {}", id);
        gameRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot to all!!

Comment: Looks like a generic homework problem.  Please describe your exact issue.  "I don't know where to start" is not a question.

Comment: I guess that "metrics" is not the right wording, you probably meant "queries" through a web API. Metrics are something you measure usually while monitoring good health of your application like average time to respond to a request, number of errors, memory consumed, etc...

Comment: Exactly Gael, queries are what I´m looking for. The problem is that I don´t know hoy to create them and make them work.

Comment: This will be the case for your whole career, a large part of your job is to learn new things mostly on your own. Start by adding your desired queries in the relevant repositories (e.g. GameRepository), write integration tests for your queries. See an introduc tion https://www.baeldung.com/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-data-jpa

Comment: Once you have written your JPA queries, you can write your REST API above them, see https://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series